# Why should I use 'unsigned' integer in this case? :

Tags: c++, unsigned-integer

```
int racer::GoodLapCount() { 
    int s = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < data.size()) {
       if (data[i].laptime < "01:30:000") {
        s++;
        }
    i++;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Can I disregard the warning 'comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions' in this case, or does it matter anything here to use it or not ?

Comment: What if the size is above the max value of an `int`?

Comment: You should use `size_t`. Or, better yet, `<your_container_type>::size_type`, where `<your_container_type>` is whatever `adat` is.

Comment: Honesly, don't even use indices, and don't loop through iterators, either. Use `std::count_if`.

Comment: sry 'adat' should means data in english

Comment: Use the same type as adat.size() returning type - that is unsinged int.
Always try to compare the same data types. Or do you need to use int?...

Comment: @bartimar, It's `std::size_t`, which is often larger than `unsigned int`.

Comment: Dávid: it's strongly encouraged to use English identifiers in your code (get used to it). Hungarian is nice (Hungarian notation is less nice), but English is the language when it comes to programming.

Comment: H2CO3 : Sry, I've just edited to the correct form!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think adat is a vector. Vector returns an unsigned integral type value, you can check this: [vector's size()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/size/)

You can ignore the warning or just use an unsigned int variable to iterate over vector. Or if you strongly need i to be a simple int variable you can roughly cast size to int

```
while(i < (int)adat.size()) {
```

but it causes problems if size is over MAX_INT value.

Furthermore, if you are using C++ 11 you can ignore the iterator variable in this way:

```
for(auto elem : adat) {
   if (elem.korido < "01:30:000") {
    s++;
}
```

Comment: Would be better `auto &elem : adat`, or else you are making copies of the elements. Or even better `const auto &elem` if you don't need to modify them (you do not).